# Will Ubuntu remove vnc in favor of freenx?

Tags: vnc, freenx

I haved tried out some of the remote control options and to me VNC feels old and slow.  Is there any chance Ubuntu will work with NX Server and bundle FreeNX and completely remove VNC as a core product.

Because it installs standard it gives the suggestion of being a relevant product but as most people replace it, I don't think it merits inclusion in the base install. Unless it's predetermined that Android will be replacing Gnome and Unity, fixing this remote tools issue seems like time well spent. Increases usability and exstends the OS family. Phone, tablet, laptop, workstation, server.

Comment: I really don't see what Android has to do with your question. Moreover, Android does not run a desktop environment like Gnome/Unity.

Answer (score 1):

While freenx will work on Ubuntu, and there are 3rd party packages for it, Ubuntu will not switch to it. It's too young a technology and too much under control of one closed source company. VNC is much wider supported and despite its speed drawbacks much more reliable and used much more than freenx.

Answer (score 1):

VNC and NX are totally different *protocols*. Therefore, you can't just drop support for one for the reason one being superior over the other in your use case.

Analogously, just because IMAP provides more features, mail user agents won't just drop POP3 support.

When it comes to *implementations* to protocols, usually coming in libraries, Ubuntu can decide which one is 'better' and to choose as the default or even drop one of them. However, most applications will just break if the library implementation changes (unless it's ABI-compatible of course).

Please remember that you can't say

> [...] VNC as a core product [...]

Because it isn't one.